# How to change values in dimens.xml

Tags: java, android, textview

Can I change variable in dimens.xml from my java code? Or it's only possible to change font size in textView through **setTextSize(value)**?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I change variable in dimens.xml from my java code?

No, you can't. Those values are static.

> Or it's only possible to change font size in textView through setTextSize(value)?

Yes, that's actually the way you're supposed to dynamically change your `TextViews` sizes.-

```
TextView yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);
yourTextView.setTextSize(20);
```

Keep in mind, however, that you should use the dimensions defined in your `dimens.xml` to do that.-

```
yourTextView.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen20));
```

Comment: Thanks :) I thought that setTextSize() is the only way.

Comment: Yeah you're right :) Actually, another approach would be using a custom style.

Comment: I would like to use variable for setTextSize() from editText or only set it when checkbox.isChecked. I'm new in android and java. Sry for stupid questions.